# Knockout: what are the event available with evet handler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

when i gone through [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html), they listed only few of them, Where i can get the complete list of events that can be used.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The knockout documentation page states that event binding is designed to be able to work with any available Javascript events.

A list is here.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

An example is here:-

```
<input 
  data-bind="
    value: linecost, 
    event: { change: function() { $parent.updateTotals() }"
/>
```